# Javascript List Item Content Advice

Tags: javascript, function, listitem

I am currently trying to learn basic Vanilla Javascript, trying being the key part. I recently built a very simple to do app following a tutorial and then I wanted to build a similar project by myself without following any tutorials. I decided to build a very simple list app that you could input your time, distance and date, obviously this isn't actually going to be used and I haven't done any design yet just some simple styles. But I would like some help with the Javascript, I have the application working in the way that I would like I just need to do the styling for when the list item is added. I have created variables for the inputs, added the event listener and run the function of creating a div container for the inputs and creating the new list items and appending, all works okay. But I don't think I have done it in the best way, the 3 inputs have separate classes and then I have created a new li item for each input. But can this been done with less code, do you have to create a new li item for each input? I tried to use querySelectorAll and gave all 3 inputs the same class but when the form submitted I got undefined not the input values. Just wanted to know if there is a better more efficient way of doing the same thing.  Thanks in advance :)

This is my HTML...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>My Treadmill Tracker</h1>
        <form action="" class="form">
          <input type="time" class="input">
          <input type="number" class="input-b" placeholder="Your Distance">
          <input type="date" class="input-c">
          <input type="submit" class="btn">
        </form>
        <ul class="list"></ul>
      </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the CSS....

```
  body{
  background: #25817c;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.form{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.input,
.input-b,
.input-c{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.input,
.input-b,
.input-c{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.input-b::placeholder{
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn{
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover{
  background: #1c6561;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit-Container{
  background: #333;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li.submitted{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

And the Javascript...

```
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const dataInput = document.querySelector(".input");
const infoContainer = document.querySelector(".list");
const dataInput2 = document.querySelector(".input-b");
const dataInput3 = document.querySelector(".input-c")

form.addEventListener("submit", formSubmit);

function formSubmit (e){
  e.preventDefault();

  const dataArea = document.createElement("div");
  dataArea.classList.add("submit-Container");

  const listInput = document.createElement("li");
  listInput.innerText = dataInput.value;
  listInput.classList.add("submitted");
  dataArea.appendChild(listInput);

  const listInput2 = document.createElement("li");
  listInput2.innerText = dataInput2.value;
  listInput2.classList.add("submitted");
  dataArea.appendChild(listInput2);

  const listInput3 = document.createElement("li");
  listInput3.innerText = dataInput3.value;
  listInput3.classList.add("submitted");
  dataArea.appendChild(listInput3);

  infoContainer.appendChild(dataArea);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved it a bit:

- You can't have a `<div>` as direct child of a `<ul>`
- Changed submit button to an HTML5 `<button>` so you can use `form.querySelectorAll("input")` without needing extra generic classes
- Made the inputs lookups to be within `<form>`
- Iterates over inputs to create `<li>`s

(This can be  further improved using a `documentFragment` to batch DOM modifications and such, but that is out of scope for a small learning example imo)

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");
const list = document.querySelector(".list")
form.addEventListener("submit", formSubmit);

function formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Array.from(inputs).forEach(createListItem);
}

function createListItem(input) {
  const listInput = document.createElement("li");
  listInput.innerText = input.value;
  listInput.classList.add("submitted");
  list.appendChild(listInput);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #25817c;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.input,
.input-b,
.input-c {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.input-b::placeholder {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #1c6561;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.submit-Container {
  background: #333;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}

li.submitted {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>My Treadmill Tracker</h1>
  <form action="" class="form">
    <input type="time" class="input">
    <input type="number" class="input-b" placeholder="Your Distance">
    <input type="date" class="input-c">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="list submit-Container"></ul>
</div>
```